# Structuring database table with large text field

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking for an advice about structuring a data table as in title to make it efficient for querying and writing. I store information about an entity which has usual data types, numbers, short string etc. Now I need to store additional field with large amount of data (~ 30 KB) and I'm looking at two options:

1. add a column an `nvarchar(100000)` in the entity table
2. create separate table to store such data and link from the entity table

other factors:

- each entity row will have an accompanying large text field
- each accompanying text field will have at least 20 KB of data
- ~20% of queries against entity table also need the large field. Other queries can do without it
- ~95% of queries seek for single entity
- I'm using an O/RM to access the data, so all the columns are pulled in (I could pick and choose by making the code look horrid)

Right now I'm leaning toward having a separate table, but it also has a bad side in that I have to remember some concerns about keeping data consistent.

It's hard to make a decision without doing a real benchmark, but this could require few days of work so I'm turning to SO for a shortcut.

Comment: I'll leave advice to others on this one, but does the data in the large text field need to be queried in terms of providing results? Maybe that would help people provide a better design too.

Comment: I would like to suggest to read about Full Text Search and ntext field.

Comment: depending on the number of rows you are dealing with the separate table may be a solution from storage perspective: you could put the 'accompanying data' table on a separate device and that may be an advantage.

Comment: Thank's everyone for insights. I would not need to query against content of large text column. I will read a bit about Full Text Search but right now it seems irrelevant as I'm not doing text search anywhere. Thank you Paolo for the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We recently had this exact problem. (though it was an XML Column instead of an NVarchar(max)) but the problem is the exact same.

Our use case was to display a list of records on a web page (the first 6 columns) of the table
and then to store a tonne of additional information in the nvarchar(max) column which got displayed once your selected an individual row.

Originally a single table contained all 7 columns.

```
TABLE 1
    INT ID (PK IDentity)
    5 other columns
    NVARCHAR(max)
```

Once we refactored it to the following we got a massive perf. boost.

```
TABLE 1
    INT ID (PK IDentity)
    5 other columns
    INT FID  (FK -TABLE2)

TABLE 2
    FID (PK IDENTITY)
    nvarchar(max)
```

The reason is that if the `nvarchar(max)` is short enough, it will be stored "in-row" but if it extends beyond the page size, then it gets stored elsewhere, and depending on a) the size of the table and record set your querying, and b) the amount of data in your `nvarchar(max)` this can have a pretty dramatic perf. drop.

Have a read of this link: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189087.aspx

> When a large value type or a large object data type column value is
>   stored in the data row, the Database Engine does not have to access a
>   separate page or set of pages to read or write the character or binary
>   string. This makes reading and writing the in-row strings about as
>   fast as reading or writing limited size varchar, nvarchar, or
>   varbinary strings. Similarly, when the values are stored off-row, the
>   Database Engine incurs an additional page read or write.

I'd bite the bullet now, and design your tables to store the large `nvarchar(max)` in a seperate table, assuming you don't need the data it contains in every `select` query

With regards, your comment about using an ORM. we were also using NHibernate in our situation. It's relatively easy to configure your mappings to lazy-load the related object on demand.

Comment: Thanks! This encouraged me to create separate table. I do have to store large XML, but I also have another column which is JSON so I tried to keep my question more general and not ask about `xml` SQL type. Thanks again.

Comment: no problem. Literally put this refactored code in Proudction in the past 2 days. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could start with documentation...

> add a column an nvarchar(100000) in the entity table

Given the documented max size of 8000 bytes for a field and thus nvarchar(4000) being the maximum, I am interested to know how you consider this an option?

nvarchar(max) - ntext etc. would be the right thing to do.

And then you should read up on full text search, which is in SQL Serve pretty much for ages. Your ORM likely does not support it though - technology choices limiting features is typical when people - have a problem abstract things. Not something I would access with an ORM.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to size limitation. I did glance at the documentation but only saw what I wanted to see ("maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes", but now that you pointed me back, i see this is for `nvarchar(max)`). As you see I am aware of ORM limitations and am ready to work around them. I don't plan to pull in megabytes of data per query.

Comment: Then the answer depends. A separate table DOES make sense for stuff like this as you can then theoreitcally also isolate this to another file group.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the only downside to having separate table is inconvenience when querying, but I'll have to be a bit less lazy.

Comment: Generally horizontal splitting (a table into multiple tables) is a viable strategy. It is used for many reasons - among them for example being able to move certain data into a separate filegroup ;) And really use a full text index ;)